# Unable to decode byte string from MQTT

Tags: python, string, byte, decode

I have a MQTT broker which is recieving data from an external publisher. When a subscriber is recieving this data it is as a byte string. Here is an example:

`payload = b'\xd1\x04\x1c\x00\x00\x00A8000_CP805x_VG_BF1702056637\x01\xe8\x03\x8f\x03\x01\x00'`

The problem is in decoding this payload.

When i try to decode it with different encodings i get:

```
encodings = ['utf-7', 'utf-8', 'utf-8-sig',
             'utf-16', 'utf-16-be', 'utf-16-le', 
             'utf-32', 'utf-32-be', 'utf-32-le',
             'ASCII', 'latin-1', 'iso-8859-1']
for enc in encodings:
    try:
        print('[' + enc + ']: \t\t' + b'\xd1\x04\x1c\x00\x00\x00A8000_CP805x_VG_BF1702056637\x01\xe8\x03\x8f\x03\x01\x00'.decode(enc))
    except Exception as e:
        print('[' + enc + ']: \t\t' + str(e))

# Output:
#[utf-7]:       'utf7' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: unexpected special character
#[utf-8]:       'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
#[utf-8-sig]:       'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
#[utf-16]:      'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 40: truncated data
#[utf-16-be]:       'utf-16-be' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 40: truncated data
#[utf-16-le]:       'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x00 in position 40: truncated data
#[utf-32]:      'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
#[utf-32-be]:       'utf-32-be' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
#[utf-32-le]:       'utf-32-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-3: code point not in range(0x110000)
#[ASCII]:       'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
#[latin-1]:         ÑA8000_CP805x_VG_BF1702056637è
#[iso-8859-1]:      ÑA8000_CP805x_VG_BF1702056637è
```

None of these are acceptable, and i am at a miss to what i can do. I'm guessing the problem is that i'm using the wrong encoding, but i unfortunately have no documentation on the payload.

**Additional information:**

The 'A8000_CP805x_VG_BF1702056637' of the byte string is a reference to the device sending the data. I am not sure if this is part of the problem.

This is only one of the payloads. There are also much larger payloads, where i get similar results that are unreadable,  but also contain non byte strings in between the bytes.

Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure the data is text, and not in some binary format?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would i check this?

Comment: The only way to be sure would be to read the documentation for the device.